# Am I able to run Unit Tests on x86 Platform Target?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, odbc

I am using VS2017 to create some new classes and run unit tests on them. These classes connect to an oracle db and we use ODBC to connect. I am using 32-bit oracle drivers on my system. The program works exactly like I want it to were it pulls info from the db. However, when I try to run unit tests for the class methods I am making they keep failing.

I have reinstalled .net core and the unit test libraries. I tried switching the build platform to x86 but when I do this the tests disappear from the Test Explorer. I have tried rebuilding after switching to the x86 platform and the tests still did not appear. I also tried reinstalling the testing dependency and the odbc dependency after switching the platform to x86, just to see if they install a different version.

```cs
// One of the tests I am trying to run
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_Info()
        {
            Info testLot = new Info();

            string testLotVar = "****";

            Assert.AreEqual(testLot.getPartNum("********").ToString(), testLotVar);
        }
```

When I try running tests they fail with this output message Message:

Test method BlankClass_UnitTests.BlankQueryClass_UnitTests.Test_Info threw exception: 
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I know that usually means the drivers do not match but I'm not seeing different platforms in the nuget manager.

When I check the application it builds fine and does what I expect so the application is talking with my driver. I am just not sure my testing library (MS Test) is

Comment: Have you tried to either set you test project to target x86 (project Properties -> Build -> Platform target), or tried setting tests projects built for AnyCPU to target x86 (Test -> Test settings -> Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects)?

Comment: @chadnt I have tried that yes. When I do that all the tests disappear from the test explorer. Then when I got to build the solution the tests are not rediscovered and the test explorer stays empty. I have also tried setting the default processor architecture and it doesn't make a difference if that is set to x86 or x64